Performing 4x4 transformation as cascade of 2x2 stages
Is there a way to perform 4x4 real invertible matrix multiplication as a cascade of (least) number of 2x2 operations where I use the input vector only in the first stage of 2x2 multiplication? It is required to use the output of any stage only once as an input to only one next stage.
I started with the following:
$\vec{Y} = M \vec{x}$, where M is a 4x4 real matrix given by
$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{12} & M_{13} & M_{14} \\
M_{21} & M_{22} & M_{23} & M_{24} \\
M_{31} & M_{32} & M_{33} & M_{34} \\
M_{41} & M_{42} & M_{43} & M_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ y_4 \end{bmatrix}$
I tried to do it as shown

the output of this form cam be written as $\vec{Y} = A \vec{x}$, then equating $A$ to $M$,
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}a_{13} & a_{13}a_{12} & a_{14}a_{31} & a_{14}a_{32} \\
a_{11}a_{23} & a_{23}a_{12} & a_{24}a_{31} & a_{24}a_{32} \\
a_{33}a_{21} & a_{33}a_{22} & a_{34}a_{41} & a_{32}a_{42} \\
a_{43}a_{21} & a_{43}a_{22} & a_{44}a_{41} & a_{44}a_{42} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ = $M = \begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{12} & M_{13} & M_{14} \\
M_{21} & M_{22} & M_{23} & M_{24} \\
M_{31} & M_{32} & M_{33} & M_{34} \\
M_{41} & M_{42} & M_{43} & M_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix}$
However, I could not find a solution to this, as for example, $\frac{a_{13}}{a_{23}}=\frac{M_{11}}{M_{21}}=\frac{M_{12}}{M_{22}}$ which does not make sense, how can I modify it to satisfy the required $M$.
Will the answer change if $M$ is unitary?

I'm honestly not sure what you're asking, but throwing this out there: if you consider your $4 \times 4$ matrix as $\pmatrix{A & B \ C & D}$ where $A, B, C, D$ are $2 \times 2$, you can multiply a vector $\pmatrix{v\w}$ where $v, w \in \Bbb{R}^2$ by $\pmatrix{Av + Bw \ Cv + Dw}$.

Hello Theo, as I pointed out, I need to use the input vectors v and w only once at the 1st stage, but in your suggestion I need to input v to two stages and w to two stages, is it clear now? or I should elaborate more? I mean by stage: 2x2 transformation

It's a little more clear, I guess. It seems, according to your flow chart, that you have no objections to having outputs from your $2 \times 2$ multiplications being used as inputs into multiple other $2 \times 2$ multiplications, right? If so, then could you not just multiply $v$ initially by $I_{2 \times 2}$, and feed the result into multiplication by $A$ and multiplication by $B$?

In my implementation, I want to avoid vectors addition for now, I just want to perform 2x2 multiplications in the flow only, do you think that is mathematically possible? In your suggestion I have to add the $Av+Bw$

I do think it's possible, but I suspect you won't like it. You can make the addition of the two vectors $Av$ and $Bw$ into a $2 \times 2$ multiplication by forming the matrix $\pmatrix{Av & Bw}$ and multiplying the vector $\pmatrix{1\1}$.

The issue is, you have used $v$ and $w$ twice, which is exactly what I don't want, you used $v$ as an input to A and also as an input to C, as in my flow, I want simply to use $v$ and $w$ only once to only one 2x2 stage for each, thanks.

Well, I would argue I haven't used $v$ or $w$ twice; I've used $I_{2 \times 2} v$ and $I_{2 \times 2} w$ twice, just as you used $\pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} \ a_{21} & a_{22}}\pmatrix{x_1\x_2}$ twice. I'm writing these as comments, because I don't believe it's what you're looking for, but I'm hoping it will help you refine your question.

Hi Theo, Yes I refined my question as it became more clear after your good comments, I added the following constraint "It is required to use the output of any stage only once as an input to only one next stage", so what do you think now? Is it possible?

Assuming I understand this restriction correctly, I would say you have defeated my method. But, I would also say you probably have defeated every other method as well. The $\Bbb{R}^2$ vector $v$ needs to interact, somehow, with eight of the sixteen entries in $M$. This $v$ can only multiply to one $2 \times 2$ matrix. Assuming this choice of $2 \times 2$ matrix is linear, there will still be a kernel of dimension at least $4$, meaning that the method will be insensitive to $4$ of the $8$ dimensions, which would prevent such a method from working.
